# Use Java to connect ethernet device

Tags: java, asyncsocket

I had a board connect to the PC using LAN cable(RJ45). I need to write the Java code to connect the board and get some data from it. How can I do it?

Actually I got a code from C++, it used `CAsyncSocket` class to do it. The C++ code is like this:

```
CAsyncSocket.Create();
CAsyncSocket.connect(IP, PORT);
```

Now, I would like to convert it into Java. Actually, I'm not so familiar with Java. Can someone show the code to me?

Example: My board IP is 192.168.2.10 and PORT is 2000. How can I connect it using Java?

Answer (score 0):

see here (for example):

```
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.2.10", 2000);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
System.out.println("Input: " + input.readLine());
socket.close();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out the socket tutorial [Lesson: All About Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/):

> URLs and URLConnections provide a relatively high-level mechanism for accessing resources on the Internet. Sometimes your programs require lower-level network communication, for example, when you want to write a client-server application.

See the [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html](Reading from and Writing to a Socket) example:

> Let's look at a simple example that illustrates how a program can establish a connection to a server program using the Socket class and then, how the client can send data to and receive data from the server through the socket.