# Send and receive data to/from a local IP address in Java

Tags: java, sockets, ip, port, ethernet

I'm new to java and now I have a problem in using Ethernet port in Java .
I have a device which can send and receive data by Ethernet . I connect it to a switch and when I enter its IP address in a browser I can see the data that the device sent ( the data is some HTML code ). But now I want to do it by a java application . If anyone can help me or send some sample code I would be grateful .
thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? WHat errors did you get? Can you show some code?

Comment: So you can access the data with a simple HTTP request?

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371943/reading-from-a-url-connection-java

Comment: I use the code that I found in this page and it did not work : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665423/use-java-to-connect-ethernet-device

Comment: yes I can send and receive data by using a web browser like chrome .

Answer (score 0):

I think tutorials on socket programming will help you.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

A very brief code may look like this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddressOfDevice);
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = socket.getOuputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out);
pw.write(yourHttpRequest);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String oneLineOfInput = br.readLine();
System.out.println(oneLineOfInput);
```

Comment: I used this code but didn't work . actually it has some problem in : String oneLineOfInput = br.readLine(); because the code stop at this line ( no error ) .